# First request doesnt terminate (no FIN) uWSGI + nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy in front of a uWSGI server (flask apps).

Due to a memory leak, use `--max-requests` to reload workers after so many calls.

The issue is the following : When a worker just restarted/started, the first request it receives stays hanging between uWSGI and NGINX, the process time inside of the flask app is usual and very quick but the client waits until `uwsgi_send_timeout` is triggered.

Using tcpdump to see the request (nginx is XXX.14 and uWSGI is XXX.11) : [image: tcpdump communcation between nginx XXX.14 and uWSGI XXX.11]

You can see in the time column that it hangs for 300 seconds (uwsgi_send_timeout) eventhough the HTTP request has been received by NGINX... uWSGI just doesn't send a [FIN] packet to signal that the connexion is closed. Then NGINX triggers the timeout and closes the session.

The end client receives a truncated response.. With a 200 status code. which is very frustrating.

This happens at every worker reload, only once, the first request no matter how big the request.

Does anyone have a workaround this issue? have I misconfigured something?

### uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
# Get the location of the app
module = api:app

plugin = python3
socket = :8000
manage-script-name = true
mount = /=api:app
cache2 = name=xxx,items=1024

# Had to increase buffer-size because of big authentication requests.
buffer-size = 8192

## Workers management
# Number of workers
processes = $(UWSGI_PROCESSES)
master = true
# Number of requests managed by 1 worker before reloading (reload is time expensive)
max-requests = $(UWSGI_MAX_REQUESTS)

lazy-apps = true

single-interpreter = true
```

### nginx-server.conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location @api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass api:8000;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 300;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some weird reason, adding the parameter `uwsgi_buffering off;` in the nginx config fixed the issue.

I still don't understand why but for now this fixes my issue. If anyone has a valid explanation, don't hesitate.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location @api {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass api:8000;
        uwsgi_buffering off;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 300;
    }
```